# Connection reset on receiving packet in UDP server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I am working on a server application (C#, .NET 4.0) that will need to handle thousands of UDP packets every second. So I decided to `SocketAsyncEventArg` to implement the server.

The problem I am facing is that my implementation receives just one packet and then I get "ConnectionReset" error (I never imagined I could get this error because UDP is connection-less). Here is my test implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpEchoServer.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            SendPacket();
        }
    }

    static void SendPacket()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SendPacket");
        var c = new UdpClient();
        c.Send(new byte[5], 5, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 445));
        c.Close();
    }
}

static class UdpEchoServer
{
    static Socket mSocket;
    static byte[] mBuffer;
    static SocketAsyncEventArgs mRxArgs, mTxArgs;
    static IPEndPoint mAnyEndPoint, mLocalEndPoint;

    public static void Start()
    {
        mAnyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        mLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 445);

        mBuffer = new byte[1024];

        mRxArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        mTxArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        mRxArgs.Completed += ReceiveComplete;
        mTxArgs.Completed += SendComplete;

        mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        mSocket.Bind(mLocalEndPoint);
        ReceiveNext();
    }

    static void ReceiveNext()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReceiveNext");

        mRxArgs.RemoteEndPoint = mAnyEndPoint;
        mRxArgs.SetBuffer(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length);

        if (!mSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(mRxArgs))
            Console.WriteLine("Error in ReceiveNext: " + mRxArgs.SocketError);
    }

    static void ReceiveComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receive Complete: " + mRxArgs.SocketError);

        if (mRxArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            return;

        mTxArgs.SetBuffer(mBuffer, 0, mRxArgs.BytesTransferred);
        mTxArgs.RemoteEndPoint = mRxArgs.RemoteEndPoint;

        Console.WriteLine("Sending reply packet");

        if (!mSocket.SendToAsync(mTxArgs))
            Console.WriteLine("Error in ReceiveComplete: " + mRxArgs.SocketError);
    }

    static void SendComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send Complete: " + mTxArgs.SocketError);

        if (mTxArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            return;

        ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

Sorry for long code but it is really simple. I wait for a packet, reply to remote end point and then wait for next one. Here is the output:

```
ReceiveNext

SendPacket
Receive Complete: Success
Sending reply packet
Send Complete: Success
ReceiveNext
Error in ReceiveNext: ConnectionReset
```

Please can you suggest what is wrong in above code snippet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens with UDP sockets. All you need to do is change [socket operating mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145152.aspx) before binding it. Use this code in your `Start` method.

```
mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

const int SIO_UDP_CONNRESET = -1744830452;
byte[] inValue = new byte[] {0};
byte[] outValue = new byte[] {0};
mSocket.IOControl(SIO_UDP_CONNRESET, inValue, outValue);

mSocket.Bind(mLocalEndPoint);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you provide an explanation please?

Comment: Just the way it is - some developer designed it like that and we have to follow :-)

Comment: This works, many thanks for sharing. I am working on a UDP socket programming course and I ran into the same problem. Adding your code to mine solves the problem but I don't know how it happened. Would be great if you could explain a little more about how and why did this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove or comment out the call to `Close` on the `UdpClient` then the program works as expected. Why this is happening I'm not sure, but it could be to do with the Windows loopback networking.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Whats more interesting is that if we keep the `Close` but run the client and server on different computers, then also problem is resolved. As you said, there must be something with windows loopback mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I'm not surprised by that. If closing a UDP socket on one host caused the closure of a UDP socket on another host I'd start to worry!